# Point-to-point video streaming

Tags: streaming

I'm looking for a software solution for streaming video with audio from one computer to another one. In my scenario, it will be over LAN but it shouldn't matter in general.

The A/V data would be sourced from a webcam and I'd like to be able to display it on the screen of receiving machine or save it to a file.

The sending machine is running Debian while the receiver can be Ubuntu or Windows 7, but I welcome options which would require a change of the OS. I also prefer free and open source software.

What I have tried so far was ffmpeg and VLC, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: FFMpeg and VLC *should* work, and I believe there aren't any alternatives (mplayer for the receiving side maybe, not sure about the sending side), so you better try to get these two to work.

Comment: @AndréDaniel It would be great if somebody actually posted that as an answer, with an example command line for ffmpeg. I'm not sure how I could approach that, ffmpeg is a great tool but so far I only had success with encoding media :s

Comment: I suggest you post a question on Unix.SE asking what you're trying to do, which hardware you're using (very important, whether it's an USB webcam, or something more exotic like an IP camera) and your attempted solutions. An answer like that would be totally off-topic on this site though.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Alright then, I'll try my luck there and come back if I get it working :) Thanks